# Enable JSP Templating on Spring 4 with Maven

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create an mvc web application using Spring.

I followed this guide http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

this works fine bur I don't understand how to use templates I'd like to have a header, footer to not repeat the code on each pages.

I'd like to use JSP but I don't understand how, there is no WEB-INF folder, no web.xml.
I don't know how to add .tag

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sample project updated, it simple configuration as you need now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add file `src/main/resources/application.properties` with content

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/ 
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

And dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Example project: [spring-boot-web-jsp-example](https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-boot-web-jsp-example)

Comment: This was prepared for your second question, but I was too late :D